# Nested and syncd listviews with Flutter (scheduler like)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm going over a few tutorials on Flutter and I'm at a point where I'm trying to build a scheduler view. I divided the layout in two list views, which are next to each other (blue and orange).
The blue list view is simple enough: 24 items, scrollable vertically.
Now the orange list view is where I'm stuck. This part should be both vertically and horizontally scrollable as a whole (notice the last cells are partially visible). Both the number of vertical and horizontal cells are known.
I tried to achieve this using nested list views, list view and child of another list view, but I get an error:

> Vertical viewport was given unbounded width.

My question is: how would I go about achieve something like this with Flutter?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Process of nesting listView.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Confirmed Request'),
      ),
        body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                nestedWidget()
            ],
        ),
    );
}
Widget nestedWidget() {
    List<Widget> listTiles = new List();
    for(int i=0;i<scheduleLists.length;i++){
      listTiles.add(getChildLists(i,scheduleLists.values.elementAt(i)));
    }
    return Column(children: listTiles,);
}

Widget getChildLists(int i, Map<String,String> tempChild){
    if(tempChild.keys.length==0){
      isEmpty = true;
      return Center(child: Container(child: Text('No data'),),);
    }
    return ListView.separated(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
        return Container(
            child: Text(tempChild.values.elementAt(index)),
        );
      },
      itemCount: tempChild.length,
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(),
    );
}
```